# Authentication failed. Either supplied credentials are invalid or the account is inactive

Tags: php, authentication, bing-ads-api

I'm trying to authenticate on Bing Ads Api but I'm getting this message:

Authentication failed. Either supplied credentials are invalid or the account is inactive

This is my code:

```
$UserName = "xxx@hotmail.com";
$Password = "xxx";
$DeveloperToken = "xxx";
$CustomerId = xxx;
$AccountId = xxx;

$wsdl = "https://campaign.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/CampaignManagement/V10/CampaignManagementService.svc?singleWsdl";
try
{
    $proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, $UserName, $Password, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, $CustomerId, null);

    // Specify one or more campaigns.

    $campaigns = array();

    $campaign = new Campaign();
    $campaign->Name = "Winter Clothing " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    $campaign->Description = "Winter clothing line.";
    $campaign->BudgetType = BudgetLimitType::MonthlyBudgetSpendUntilDepleted;
    $campaign->MonthlyBudget = 1000.00;
    $campaign->TimeZone = "PacificTimeUSCanadaTijuana";
    $campaign->DaylightSaving = true;
    // Used with FinalUrls shown in the ads that we will add below.
    $campaign->TrackingUrlTemplate = 
       "http://tracker.example.com/?season={_season}&promocode={_promocode}&u={lpurl}";
    $campaigns[] = $campaign;
    // Add the campaign, ad group, keywords, and ads

    $campaignIds = AddCampaigns($proxy, $AccountId, $campaigns);
    PrintCampaignIdentifiers($campaignIds);

}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    // Output the last request/response.

    print "\nLast SOAP request/response:\n";
    print $proxy->GetWsdl() . "\n";
    print $proxy->GetService()->__getLastRequest()."\n";
    print $proxy->GetService()->__getLastResponse()."\n";

    // Campaign Management service operations can throw AdApiFaultDetail.
    if (isset($e->detail->AdApiFaultDetail))
    {
        // Log this fault.

        print "The operation failed with the following faults:\n";

        $errors = is_array($e->detail->AdApiFaultDetail->Errors->AdApiError)
        ? $e->detail->AdApiFaultDetail->Errors->AdApiError
        : array('AdApiError' => $e->detail->AdApiFaultDetail->Errors->AdApiError);

        // If the AdApiError array is not null, the following are examples of error codes that may be found.
        foreach ($errors as $error)
        {
            print "AdApiError\n";
            printf("Code: %d\nError Code: %s\nMessage: %s\n", $error->Code, $error->ErrorCode, $error->Message);

            switch ($error->Code)
            {
                case 105:  // InvalidCredentials
                    break;
                case 117:  // CallRateExceeded
                    break;
                default:
                    print "Please see MSDN documentation for more details about the error code output above.\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed reply. I noticed that you are setting the UserName to ***@hotmail.com. If you are using an email address login i.e. Microsoft account, then you must use OAuth i.e. set the AuthenticationToken header element instead of setting the UserName/Password fields.